# ag-Grid How to prevent default sort and filter?

Tags: sorting, filtering, ag-grid

I am using Client-side Row Model for aggrid, but i want to sort and filter by server-side, I don't know how to prevent the behavior of sort and filter by aggrid itself.

Comment: I have a similar issue and the best solution so far is to implement custom header components, than listen for clicks on those components and implement custom sorting. what I found more difficult with this approach is to set/reset header cell sorting status, especially when I want to sort by different columns, but it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

For the sorting:
I am having the same issue, I did a simple trick by using a mock sort comparator.

Add to each column object in columnsDefs array a "comparator" property returning 0 like:

```
columnDefs = columnDefs.map(colDef => ({
   ...colDef,
    comparator: () => 0
}));
```

In this way we say that the custom sorting comparator returns the same data, so you can still get benefit from the sorting icons.

Moreover, and in order to get the sorted data from the server, you just need to listen to sort change event like:

`(sortChanged)="onSortChanged($event)"`

Then in onSortChanged:

```
onSortChanged(event){
    const sortModel = this.gridApi.getSortModel();
    service.getDataFromServer(sortModel);
    refreshGrid(); // If needed
}
```